# Hosted analytics with scheduled reports to customers

Tags: report, azure-sql-database, analytics

I've been hunting the interwebs for days on this and keep coming up with little to nothing.

I have a requirement where our company needs to send scheduled reports to our customers about analytics. Think: engagement, views, etc.

This report would be in the form of an email with a summary, and and attached PDF with pretty graphs etc. Basically doing something to what [Quill Engage](https://www.quillengage.com/) does for GA data, but using our own application data.

Essentially, i'd like to import my data (SQL Azure) into a service (with a periodic refresh), segment the data based on my customers (e.g a 'user id'), then send this segmented data to each customer on a scheduled basis.

SQL Server Reporting Services simply won't be pretty enough - these need to be branded, pretty emails going to customers.

I was looking at [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) initially for analytics, but it doesn't do scheduled reports.

The closest thing i found to this was [Zoho Reports](https://www.zoho.com/reports/).

The only other option i can think of is using a PDF merge service like [Webmerge](https://www.webmerge.me/). But that means i'd need to write my own code to grab data, call into the API and generate an email.

There is no shortage of analytics SaaS products out there, but not many seem to support scheduled reports to *customers*, segmenting the data (most seem tailored to internal company emails).

Can anyone give me some advice?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The only challenge, is that the customer list grows dynamically. The analytics are based on customer application data, so every month there could be new customer data, and new customers to email. Most services seem to require the recipients to be 'known' when the schedule is setup. So i'd need a service which takes a dynamic recipient list.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at [beekeeper data](http://beekeeperdata.com), still not 100% sure it will be a great solution for your specific case(however, I am quite positive that they support scheduled reports to emails)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks interesting. See my edit though..doesn't seem like beekeeper supports this. Does it?

Comment: As far as I can see(and know), – you can re-configure your recipient list when you need to. You can check out few pages of interface with email reports at [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxKFMWWl_dI) . On minute 6-7(around 6:50, to be specific) he clicks on email reports page. Also, sending them email with your questions will be helpful too: )
Cheers.

Comment: I'd be sending more than 100 emails a month, so that's means i'd need the $799 a month plan :(